# What should I do to make a subclass of UIViewController a singleton?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What modification should I use?

Is this a good idea?

I notice that - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil is never really called

The purpose is Easier debugging. Ensuring that forms that should only have one form indeed has only one form.

There are many purposes actually.

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting it to be a singleton?

Comment: Easier debugging. Ensuring that forms that should only have one form indeed has only one form.

Comment: The reason why `-initWithNibName:bundle:` isn't being called is because `-initWithCoder:` is.

Comment: Rather than a UIViewController singleton, why don't you make a separate singleton class which handles all your form stuff? After all, the VC is just to handle the display

Comment: That is my design now. Hmm... Sometimes I want to do some process and tell a subclass of uiviewcontroller to update one of it's outlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to use a singleton in your situation. But an easy way to implement it is through a macro, check this article: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html